# Json com uma lista vazia C#

Tags: c#, json

Tenho a seguinte dúvida tenho uma classe que contem uma lista e tenho outra classe que lê um *JSON* a Classe de leitura chama a classe Entidade e monta o objeto mas quando uma das listas vem vazia ela da o seguinte erro.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Entidades.FreightValue' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '[0].freightValue', line 1, position 165.

Alguém sabe como deserializar um *JSON* mesmo quando há uma lista vazia

### JSON:

```
[{
    "id": "11cc404",
    "slaType": "Normal",
    "name": "teste",
    "scheduledDelivery": false,
    "maxRangeDelivery": 0,
    "dayOfWeekForDelivery": null,
    "dayOfWeekBlockeds": [],
    "freightValue": [],
    "factorCubicWeight": null,
    "freightTableProcessStatus": 1,
    "freightTableValueError": null,
    "modals": [],
    "onlyItemsWithDefinedModal": false,
    "deliveryOnWeekends": false,
    "carrierSchedule": [],
    "maxDimension": {
        "weight": 0.0,
        "height": 0.0,
        "width": 0.0,
        "length": 0.0,
        "maxSumDimension": 0.0
    },
    "exclusiveToDeliveryPoints": false,
    "minimunCubicWeight": 0.0,
    "isPolygon": false,
    "numberOfItemsPerShipment": null
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "slaType": "Normal",
    "name": "Transportadora",
    "scheduledDelivery": false,
    "maxRangeDelivery": 0,
    "dayOfWeekForDelivery": null,
    "dayOfWeekBlockeds": [],
    "freightValue": [],
    "factorCubicWeight": null,
    "freightTableProcessStatus": 1,
    "freightTableValueError": null,
    "modals": [],
    "onlyItemsWithDefinedModal": false,
    "deliveryOnWeekends": false,
    "carrierSchedule": [],
    "maxDimension": {
        "weight": 0.0,
        "height": 0.0,
        "width": 0.0,
        "length": 0.0,
        "maxSumDimension": 0.0
    },
    "exclusiveToDeliveryPoints": false,
    "minimunCubicWeight": 0.0,
    "isPolygon": false,
    "numberOfItemsPerShipment": null
}]
```

A lista que esta vindo vazia no caso é a `freightValue`.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


    namespace Entidades
    {
        [DataContract(Name = "RootElement")]
public class ETransportadora
{
    public ETransportadora()
    {
        listaTransportadoras = new List<Transportadora>();
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Property1")]
    public List<Transportadora> listaTransportadoras { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Name = "Property1")]
public class Transportadora
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "slaType")]
    public string slaType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "scheduledDelivery")]
    public bool scheduledDelivery { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "maxRangeDelivery")]
    public int maxRangeDelivery { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "dayOfWeekForDelivery")]
    public object dayOfWeekForDelivery { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "dayOfWeekBlockeds")]
    public object[] dayOfWeekBlockeds { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "freightValue")]
    public FreightValue freightValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "factorCubicWeight")]
    public object factorCubicWeight { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "freightTableProcessStatus")]
    public int freightTableProcessStatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "freightTableValueError")]
    public object freightTableValueError { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "modals")]
    public object[] modals { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "onlyItemsWithDefinedModal")]
    public bool onlyItemsWithDefinedModal { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "deliveryOnWeekends")]
    public bool deliveryOnWeekends { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "carrierSchedule")]
    public object[] carrierSchedule { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "maxDimension")]
    public Maxdimension maxDimension { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "exclusiveToDeliveryPoints")]
    public bool exclusiveToDeliveryPoints { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "minimunCubicWeight")]
    public float minimunCubicWeight { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "isPolygon")]
    public bool isPolygon { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "numberOfItemsPerShipment")]
    public object numberOfItemsPerShipment { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Name = "Maxdimension")]
public class Maxdimension
{
    [DataMember(Name = "weight")]
    public float weight { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "height")]
    public float height { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "width")]
    public float width { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "length")]
    public float length { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "maxSumDimension")]
    public float maxSumDimension { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Name = "FreightValue")]
public class FreightValue
{
    [DataMember(Name = "zipCodeStart")]
    public float zipCodeStart { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "zipCodeEnd")]
    public float zipCodeEnd { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "weightStart")]
    public float weightStart { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "weightEnd")]
    public float weightEnd { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "absoluteMoneyCost")]
    public float absoluteMoneyCost { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "pricePercent")]
    public float pricePercent { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "pricePercentByWeight")]
    public float pricePercentByWeight { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "maxVolume")]
    public float maxVolume { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "timeCost")]
    public float timeCost { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "country")]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "operationType")]
    public int operationType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "restrictedFreights")]
    public object restrictedFreights { get; set; }
}
}


    private ETransportadora ListarTodasTransportadoras()
    {

        ETransportadora lst = new ETransportadora();
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Transportadora>> (content);
        foreach (var transp in results)
        {
            lst.listaTransportadoras.Add(transp);
        }   

        return lst;
    }
```

Comment: Podes colocar a definição das classes? Precisamos dum [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para replicar o problema e poder ajudar.

Comment: dependendo da bilioteca que vc está usando para desserializar o objeto, ogar num objeto dinâmico e depois fazer o de-para é uma solução...

Comment: @CaiqueC. Se a intenção for extrair 1 ou 2 valores do JSON, sim, usar um objecto dinamico (ou `JToken` no caso de JSON.NET) é uma solução rápida. Se a intenção for usar a totalidade, ou a maioria, dos dados, então usar compilação dinamica é uma péssima solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está aqui:

```
public FreightValue freightValue { get; set; }
```

Como tu próprio disseste, `freightValue` é uma lista de objectos. Então, a propriedade também tem de ser uma colecção (ex: `List<T>`)

```
public List<FreightValue> freightValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado realmente resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Teste se a lista com os itens não está vazia através de uma condicional (if, por exemplo), e somente chame a classe de leitura se esta lista não estiver vazia, assim você também poupa recursos da aplicação.

Um Json vazio seria um colchete aberto e fechado ("{}")

Espero ter ajudado